# Mark the region defined by an inequality inside Plot3D

Tags: plotting, regions

I have function like this

```
Plot3D[1.11956 Sqrt[(Sqrt[\[Psi]] (1 + 2 \[Psi])^(3/2))/(dy^4 (1 + \[Psi]))], 
{\[Psi],0,10},{dy,0,10}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "dy", "dx"}]
```

I have a region plot given by

```
k2 = RegionPlot[1 < dx/dy < 8, {dx, 0, 10}, {dy, 0, 10}]
```

Now I want the region defined by this equality inside the Plot3D

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Show[{
  Plot3D[1.11956 Sqrt[(Sqrt[\[Psi]] (1 + 2 \[Psi])^(3/
           2))/(dy^4 (1 + \[Psi]))], {\[Psi], 0, 10}, {dy, 0, 10}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\[Psi]", "dy", "dx"}, PlotRange -> {0, 10}],
  RegionPlot3D[
   1 < dx/dy < 8, {\[Psi], 0.1, 10}, {dy, 0.1, 10}, {dx, 0.1, 10}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.7]]
  }]
```

with the following effect

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

```
plt1 = Plot3D[1.11956 Sqrt[(Sqrt[ψ] (1 + 2 ψ)^(3/2))/(dy^4 (1 + ψ))], 
   {ψ, 0, 10}, {dy, 0, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"ψ", "dy", "dx"}, 
  RegionFunction -> (Not[1 < #3/#2 <= 8] &), PlotRange -> {0, 10}, Mesh -> None]; 
plt2 =  Plot3D[1.11956 Sqrt[(Sqrt[ψ] (1 + 2 ψ)^(3/2))/(dy^4 (1 + ψ))], 
   {ψ, 0, 10}, {dy, 0, 10}, 
  RegionFunction -> (1 < #3/#2 <= 8 &), PlotStyle -> Red, Mesh -> None];
Show[plt1, plt2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot3D[
 dx == 1.11956 Sqrt[(Sqrt[ψ] (1 + 2 ψ)^(3/2))/(dy^4 (1 + ψ))],
 {ψ, 0, 10}, {dy, 0, 10}, {dx, 0, 10},
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{ψ, dy, dx}, dx/dy], Mesh -> {{1, 8}},
  MeshShading -> {Yellow, Red}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

The setting `Mesh -> {{1, 8}}` divides the range into three pieces, below 1, between 1 and 8, and above 8.  The setting `MeshShading -> {Yellow, Red}` is a list of colors, applied cyclically, to the three regions (hence `Yellow`, `Red`, `Yellow`):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same idea can be applied to `Plot3D`, but `ContourPlot3D` does a better job of meshing the steep part of the graph:

```
Plot3D[1.11956 Sqrt[(Sqrt[ψ] (1 + 2 ψ)^(3/2))/(dy^4 (1 + ψ))],
 {ψ, 0, 10}, {dy, 0, 10},
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{ψ, dy, dx}, dx/dy], Mesh -> {{1, 8}},
 MeshShading -> {Yellow, Red}, AxesLabel -> {"ψ", "dy", "dx"}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 10}]
```